# From a list of dictionaries which all have the same keys, most pythonic way to get values of the same key from all dictionaries

Tags: python

Say I have a list of dictionaries like this

```
sampDic = [
{"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
{"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
{"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]
```

I want to get the 'name' value for all the dictionaries.

I tried

```
sampDic[:]['name']
```

but that gives an

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-924869e29ce4> in <module>()
----> 1 sampDic[:]['name']

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

error.

So the best I can come up with is

```
for item in sampDic:
     print(item['name'])
```

Is there a more efficient and/or pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Use a list comprehension: `[d['name'] for d in sampDic]` Maybe worth renaming `sampDic` to `sampList`

Comment: Your approach is perfectly pythonic.